# Create a black and white map with ggmaps

Tags: r, plot, ggmap

I want to produce a map in R of north America. I made it work to get in google style, however I would rather have it in a black an white layout, where  the countries a blank and the boarders a black. Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Add `color = "bw"` to your `get_map` call?

Comment: Then I get a black and white image of the map, but I just want the contours of the countries

Answer (score 1):

That would do it ; You just need to enter your long and lat

```
library(ggmap)
gc <- data.frame(lon=XXX, lat=XXX)
center <- as.numeric(gc)
beb<-ggmap(get_googlemap(center = center, scale = 2, zoom=9, maptype="terrain", color="bw"), extent = "device" )
```